# why ambari agent insist to create another repository file

Tags: linux, redhat, hadoop, big-data

we are installing the new hadoop version - **2.6.3.0** on ambari - **2.6.0**

from ambari agent log we see the follwing:

```
Writing File['/etc/yum.repos.d/ambari-hdp-51.repo'] because contents don't match
```

why ambari create the file - ambari-hdp-51.repo ,  ?
is it possible to disable this action ? ( I mean how to configure amabri to not create this repo file ? )

it is very strange that ambari create this repo and that because under /etc/yum.trepo.d ,

we already have the repo files for ambari & hadoop 
so why ambari insist to create the file - ambari-hdp-51.repo **and how to disable** it?

full log:

```
vi /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/output-370.txt
2018-01-04 14:40:06,895 - Will install packages for repository version 2.6.3.0
2018-01-04 14:40:06,895 - Repository['HDP-2.6-repo-55'] {'append_to_file': False, 'base_url': 'http://master02.sys453.com/HDP/centos7/2.6.3.0-235', 'action': ['create'], 'components': [u'HDP', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'ambari-hdp-55', 'mirror_list': None}
2018-01-04 14:40:06,939 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/ambari-hdp-55.repo'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...)}
2018-01-04 14:40:06,941 - Writing File['/etc/yum.repos.d/ambari-hdp-55.repo'] because it doesn't exist
2018-01-04 14:40:06,942 - Repository['HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21-repo-55'] {'append_to_file': True, 'base_url': 'http://master02.sys453.com/', 'action': ['create'], 'components': [u'HDP-UTILS', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'ambari-hdp-55', 'mirror_list': None}
2018-01-04 14:40:06,950 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/ambari-hdp-51.repo'] {'content': '[HDP-2.6-repo-51]\nname=HDP-2.6-repo-51\nbaseurl=http://master02.ipmassanalyt71.com/HDP/centos7/2.6.3.0-235\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0\n[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21-repo-51]\nname=HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21-repo-51\nbaseurl=http://master02.ipmassanalyt71.com/\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0'}
2018-01-04 14:40:06,951 - Writing File['/etc/yum.repos.d/ambari-hdp-51.repo'] because contents don't match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During my observations when I used the Hortonworks packages is that always you install, reinstall and sometimes, restart any commponets the default action is recreate you local repository file (.repo) to e nsure that the information about the repositories registred on ambari configurations is right on your .repo files.

This problem is happened with me when I try to install the Hortonworks packages inside a Docker container.